# Creating a website with a wallet, similar to how etherdelta handles its exchange?

Tags: transactions, wallets

I don't have any intention of doing anything on the scale of an exchange. Just trying to do a little research into how difficult it would be and what technologies would be required.

Basically wondering how difficult it would be to set up a website with functionality similar to EtherDelta without the exchange. Just an account on the website with the balance of 1 token and the ability to withdraw/deposit that 1 token.

I'm completely unfamiliar with crypto, but thought of a fun little project I could muck around with, so trying to gauge how long it would take. The only hurdle I can think of is incorporating the token into the website.

Also, what technologies would be best for this? I've only vaguely looked into it as I figured just asking on here would be much quicker. I'm most familiar with PHP and vanilla JS. Is that possible, or would I have to use Node?

Thanks.